# Virtual Keyboard - button keys Up, Down, Left, Right in TextBox

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm working on a virtual keyboard (homework from school) and using visual basic express.
I would like to ask if you could help me with the arrow button keys. I got stuck there. I'm using a textbox and I don't know what code I should use for each key to actually jump a line UP (for the up arrow button), DOWN (for the down arrow button), LEFT and RIGHT for each button as well.

Comment: Is your question about programmatically moving the cursor in a (multiline) textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Give your TextBox focus, then use [SendKeys.Send()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.8).

Here's an example with the Up arrow:

```
Private Sub btnUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUp.Click
    TextBox1.Focus()
    SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
End Sub
```

Use the link to figure out the other arrow keys.

Comment: Its not working, i dont know why. It let me to start it but its not actually doing anything when i press it. It wont go on another line.

Comment: Update your original post with the code you're using.